# Raspberry Pi i2c master access to slave TI MSP2553 uC - hangs the uC ~1 in 1000 accesses

Tags: linux

I slowed down the i2c clock freq, beefed up the PSupply, changed pull-up resistors - no change. However I made the "errors" increase significantly by busying the ARM with 2 calculation-intensive programs. I use Python in RPi, using smbus, SMBUS and i2c_LCD_driver. I use C to manage interrupts in the MSP430. try/except routine catches the bad access and resets the MSP - accesses every 5 seconds continues fine until the next hang. Is this a known ARM/Linux OS issue?

Comment: Try https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com. Also, from your descriptions it's not clear if it hangs on the RaspPi or the MSP side (at least not clear to me).

Comment: sorry... it's the MSP that gets reset and the i2c bus goes normal. I'll chekc out the link you sent ... THanks!

Comment: I know both devices have hardware state machines that manage the i2c.  Given that I can hang the bus by overworking the RPi, my suspicion was/is the implementation of the python code and/or OS.  Are you aware of any weird stuff the OS can do to the BSC i2c controller in the ARM  that would keep the MSP from finishing it's state machine run ?

Comment: Thanks ... will repost in raspberrypi.stackexchange.com